# BotFramework Get count of button click ( OpenURL)

Tags: botframework, chatbot

In our botframework chatbot application we have URLs ( buttons - OpenURL)  which will redirect to website / mobile apps links.  How we will be able to get the statistics or number of hits happened to a particular website URL.

Thank you 
AMR

Comment: By logging them?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the bot. The "OpenUrl" protocol tells the channel to just open the link on the button. This doesn't trigger a message so the bot will not know that the button was clicked.

The only solution I can think of is creating a special url which will first log the action and then redirect the user to the requested webpage. But this solution  requires you to setup your own website or api.

Comment: The bot is already a website, so just exposing an endpoint for redirection should work.  (Nice idea!)